# Node.js find all undefinded variable from project

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, configuration, syntax-error

I am developing a backend API with Node.js
Some times, i cannot make unit test, and, `data is not defined` error occurs
With typescript, we can solve this problem with the lint system.
Angular 9 project, the compiler system detects that problem, and, this error will solve automatically.

but, How I can configure with node.js project?

I checked esLint tools, but, it seems working with `ts` file

Comment: Seen as you have used Typescript, I would just use Typescript for node too.  JavaScript even with a good linter has limited scope.

Comment: You don't show actual code for the situation you're trying to detect so we can't really help you with anything specific.  The general tools for Javascript are running in strict mode or a lint tool and then move to TypeScript if you want more than that.  FYI, nothing related to any of this prevents you from writing a unit test so perhaps you're confused by something else.  Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eslint is solve my problems
Also, I used git hook to check the eslint before git commit
https://gist.github.com/linhmtran168/2286aeafe747e78f53bf

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": [
      "off",
      4,
      {
        "FunctionDeclaration": {
          "parameters": "first"
        },
        "FunctionExpression": {
          "parameters": "first"
        },
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      {
        "code": 1000
      }
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "off",
      "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
      "warn",
      "always"
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "off",
      {
        "args": "after-used",
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^next$"
      }
    ],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "off",
      "always-multiline"
    ],
    "arrow-parens": [
      0,
      "as-needed",
      {
        "requireForBlockBody": true
      }
    ],
    "eol-last": [
      "off",
      "always"
    ],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      "off",
      {
        "max": 1,
        "maxEOF": 0
      }
    ],
    "prefer-const": "off",
    "no-var": "off",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": [
      "off"
    ],
    "object-curly-spacing": [
      "off",
      "always"
    ],
    "camelcase": "off",
    "eqeqeq": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-control-regex": 0,
    "no-useless-escape": 0,
    "no-constant-condition": "off",
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": "off",
    "no-empty": "off",
    "no-redeclare": "off",
    "no-self-assign": "off",
    "no-async-promise-executor": "off"
  }
}
```